# how to extract a number followed by a specific word using RegEX python

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe of string texts example:

```
descripton
..32 cars are coming full of attendees..
..64 attendees..
..8 participants are allowed..
```

I want to extract using regex the number plus a specific word "participant or participants, attendant or attendees" after it immediately, so the output from this column should be:

```
64 attendees
8 participants
```

and I will save the output in a new column using pandas.

I tried this code:

```
data['affluence0'] = data['description'].str.findall(r'\d+(?= [personnes|participants|membres])')
```

but it's extracting all digits from the column and all these specific 3 words from every row. I want only the number followed by these specific keywords.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/t2wbx4/1

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["new column"] = df["description"].str.extract(
    r"(\d+\s+(?:participants?|attendant|attendees))"
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                description      new column
0  ..32 cars are coming full of attendees..             NaN
1                          ..64 attendees..    64 attendees
2            ..8 participants are allowed..  8 participants
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
import re

target = ['attendees', 'participants']

regex = f'(\d+\s*(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, target))}))'
# '(\\d+\\s*(?:attendees|participants))'
df['new'] = df['descripton'].str.extract(regex)
```

output:

```
                                 descripton             new
0  ..32 cars are coming full of attendees..             NaN
1                          ..64 attendees..    64 attendees
2            ..8 participants are allowed..  8 participants
```